# Tool to generate sequence diagram from react.js source code

Tags: reactjs, reverse-engineering

I am learning react.js from an online tutorial. The source code is provided in the tutorial itself. It will be useful if I can view the sequence diagram displaying interaction between components, actions dispatched, classes ,stateless functions and higher-order functions used in the project and the overall architecture and organization of the project, when the source code is supplied to certain tool. Is there any tool available to get this done?

Comment: Nope. I have tried looking in the past and couldn't find any.

Comment: @MukeshSoni Please look into this module 
https://github.com/React-Sight/React-Sight

Comment: Looks cool. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found a tool called `React-Sight` :

https://github.com/React-Sight/React-Sight